# Why when i use & in my Qt strings

Tags: c++, qt

When i use & in my ui namings, instead of shortcut(ex: Alt+C), its type & in output.

```
label = new QLabel(tr("&Cell Location"));
```

and my label name after run is: &Cell Location.

Comment: Maybe Labels do not support shortcuts.. have you tried this with menu entries?

Comment: Try without tr. Just new QLabel("&Cell location", this)

Comment: @kazemakase No, [QLabel clearly supports shortcuts](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#setBuddy).

Comment: You know, in my last project, i do this correctly with labels and menu entries and buttons, but in this new project, specially when i use form view, and try to edit names graphically, it doesn't work.

Comment: @unwind That is interesting. I was not aware of buddy widgets. :)

Comment: label = new QLabel(tr("&Cell Location"));
    lineEdit = new QLineEdit;
    label->setBuddy(lineEdit); i use setBuddy! and it works!

Comment: but, i think its not good, because i couldn't use this parameter in ui view and edit!

Comment: you can set buddies in the QtCreator's designer try the button with the orange marker up top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you need to also *use* the shortcut, by linking the label with a "buddy widget", [as the documentation shows](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#setBuddy):

```
QLineEdit *nameEd = new QLineEdit(this);
QLabel    *nameLb = new QLabel("&Name:", this);
nameLb->setBuddy(nameEd);
```

Comment: i found it bro, but i want to know, how this problem fixed when i use form edit view, i only double click on label and type &Cell. and the out put is exactly &Cell : )